# Getting NUnit AssertionException when verifying list is sorted and items have special characters

Tags: c#, sorting, testing, nunit, assert

I'm getting NUnit.Framework.AssertionException Expected:collection ordered. 
When trying to verify the sorting is ascending with the next code:

```
var anotherList = new List<string> { "www.word-edit.officeapps.live.com", "www.wordclouds.com" };
Assert.That(anotherList, Is.Ordered.Ascending);
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or missing something? Are there another approach I can follow?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is failing because those strings are not in ascending order. It fails at `word-e` of first string and `wordc` of second string where `c` is before `e` and hyphen is ignored by default. If you want to include the hyphen in ordering use `StringComparer.Ordinal`:

```
Assert.That(anotherList, Is.Ordered.Ascending.Using((IComparer)StringComparer.Ordinal));
```

Now the test will succeed.

Comment: So, Is.Ordered.Ascending is taking "word-e" like "workde"?, What if hyphen should be considered in sorting validation?

Comment: hyphens are ignored unless you use `CompareOrdinal`. check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Now StringComparer includes hyphen in sorting validation, but now I faced with underscores and test failed again. Another Question?

Comment: can you provide example?

Comment: Example List: "note_1","note1","note2","note3"

Comment: if you use `Ordinal` for that, `note_1` will be last.. you should remove `Using(...)` clause and go with default. Also `-` < `_`, check http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, abdul
In some cases, if your collection has an UpperCase item, you should use StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase instead of StringComparer.Ordinal

Comment: If you're trying to reply to someone's answer, please post as a comment under their answer, not as a separate answer.

Comment: I'd like, but this function is disabled forme, it's required repetition -50 points((